# Couldn't generate Android App Bundle version of my App

Tags: litho, facebook-litho

Is anyone else facing this problem?

I can generate Debug and Release versions of my App in Bundle Package. No gradle erros during the Assemble.

Dependencies:

```
// Litho
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-core:0.19.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-widget:0.19.0'
compileOnly 'com.facebook.litho:litho-annotations:0.19.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.facebook.litho:litho-processor:0.19.0'

// Sections
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-core:0.19.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-widget:0.19.0'
compileOnly 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-annotations:0.19.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.facebook.litho:litho-sections-processor:0.19.0'

// SoLoader
implementation 'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.5.1'
```

But when I run it on the Android Device, app crashes and logcat shows it:

```
2019-03-22 12:59:40.128 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /data/app/br.com.hinorede.app-aqB3syBNAjQg9cbzWpXDQg==/lib/arm64
2019-03-22 12:59:40.129 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /system/vendor/lib
2019-03-22 12:59:40.129 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app D/SoLoader: libyoga.so not found on /system/lib
2019-03-22 12:59:40.131 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libyoga.so
2019-03-22 12:59:40.131 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

2019-03-22 12:59:40.137 18103-18103/br.com.hinorede.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.hinorede.app, PID: 18103
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libyoga.so
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:703)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:564)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:500)
at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:455)
```

If I run the app using the traditional method (Apk File) it works fine. But when I run from the bundle it crashes.

Anyone?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a demo project where this can be tested?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I zipped a demo project this link: https://mega.nz/#!Fpd1gAqA!5uuEEqoCx3Wbec8amYqJV84rkx6EBZD8b4uXV1kHHTI

To reproduce the crash, you need to:
1 - In Android Studio 3.3.2 go to "Run" > "Edit Configurations"
2 - In general tab > "Deploy:" choose "APK from app bundle" hit "OK"
3 - Run (^R)